# Auto formatting - Eclipse C++

Tags: c++, eclipse, eclipse-cdt

Hi all I'm trying to stop the auto formatting in eclipse from indenting my opening and close brace after a function that has a throw() statement on the end.

e.g

```
void function(std::string param) throw()
{

}
```

after auto format will look like this:

```
void function(std::string param) throw()
  {

  }
```

But it will carry on adding another tab to the front of the brackets every time I autoformat my code. Anyone know how I can turn this feature off, or is it a bug

Eclipse info: 
Version: Juno Release
Build id: 20120614-1722
using CDT

**Note:**
I am using my own code style profile.

Comment: What profile is your code style profile based on? Also check that the code has not errors before changing the profile to Allman and applying syntax format

Comment: Mainly GNU and Allaman. Even with error free code and even with the use of Astyle, this problem still exists. I think this is probably more likely  a bug with the Juno release of eclipse as it does not occur on the Indigo version. I was just wondering if anyone else experiences this issue.

Answer (score 5):

The name of that style is [*Whitesmiths*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indent_style#Whitesmiths_style) - Try to change it to [*Allman*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indent_style#Allman_style).

In C/C++ perspective mode, Goto Window > Preferences > C/C++ > Code Style

[image]

Choose BSD/Allman or whatever you want.

Comment: h that would of been helpful however i'm using Juno (the non android version) and that file menu is not present.

Comment: Maybe there is something similar in your IDE, isn't it?

Comment: Even if I change to the Allman style in the profile this function still happens :(

Answer (score 1):

You might want to consider [Astyle](http://astyleclipse.sourceforge.net/), this is a eclipse plguin, an interface to a wondeful code beautyfication command line tool. you can set the indentation, formatting, etc.
Very handy tool.